# How to color-code 2D scatter plot based on a 3rd column

Tags: python

I have a scatter plot with the x and y axes showing distance and temperature, respectively. The data was collected over multiple days, and I want to color-code the plot to see which data was collected on which date (e.g., 20160703). How can I add color based on the "date" column?

Comment: What module are you using for reading and writing excel files? If you don't know it depends on what file extension. If it is xls i recommend pyexcel which is a wrapper for xlrd and xlwt. If it is xlsx I recommend openpyxl. Also what have you tried so far at this point? Can you take a screenshot of the excel file and upload it?

Comment: Here is the documentation for pyexcel: http://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/. Here is the documentation for openpyxl: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your using xlsx as that is the newest excel file format.

For xlsx you are going to want to use openpyxl.

Documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

Here is the specific documentation for color: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/styles/colors.html

If I understand correctly here is what you want:

```
import openpyxl
x = 0

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

ws = wb.active

columnName = ['Date']

for cell in columnName:
    cell.style = COLOR_INDEX[X]
    x += 1



wb.save(filename.xlsx)
```